# ViewHolder attribute changes affects Objects attribute

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewholder

```
private fun turnOnAllItems() {
    items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        val viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(index)
                as SwitchableItemViewHolder
        viewHolder.switchButton.isChecked = false
    }
}
```

What this does, is it also changes list `items` object values `isEnabled` to false. Looks weird to me, as I actually change viewHolder attribute. Why is this happening? How to avoid this?

Comment: Do you have an `OnCheckedChangeListener` on `switchButton`? If so, that would be why. You should instead be updating the dataset, then notifying the changes on the `Adapter`. `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition()` will return null for items that aren't currently laid out.

Comment: @MikeM. I changed to `setOnClickListener` but it also changed object values.

Comment: Well, first off, why wouldn't you want the dataset and the UI to match? Beyond that, I don't believe there's enough information to determine the cause of that issue. However, as I mentioned, you really shouldn't be doing it like that, anyway. You would want to update the dataset, then notify. Don't try to directly manipulate the `View`s like that. It's not going to work if there are more items than are displayed at a time. Not every item will have a `ViewHolder`, in that case.

Comment: @MikeM. Well, I've a bigger switch, that turns off all children switches, but the moment I turn on big switch it should turn on only previously enabled switched (basically I've to save state). I guess better way would be to make a list of Boolean values that do that?

Comment: Yeah, you're going to need an additional state variable for the items for that, however you want to handle it. Otherwise, scrolling would mess that all up anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that you are doing it the wrong way. RecyclerView is meant to display already modified data, meaning that you have a set of it.

Let's say, 10 tables in restaurant, and at some point table #4 becomes available for new customer and you want to indicate that.

A good approach would be to modify your list of tables somewhere outside RCV, even fragment or activity will do, and then just graphically update (all or just one) item by means of RCV.

Here's a little [article](https://medium.com/androidsolutions/recyclerview-adapters-4d39a24da3c0) I made to illustrate how to properly use `RecyclerView`, hope it will help you